# Celery tasks immediately autodiscover

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to build an application on top of Celery framework.

I have a module `settings/celery_settings.py` with the code that initializes Celery application like this (I expand some variables):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

pfiles = ['other_tasks.test123', 'balance_log.balance_log']
app = Celery('myapp')
# here I just have some parameters defined like broker, result backend, etc
# app.config_from_object(settings)

# TRYING to discover tasks
app.autodiscover_tasks(pfiles)
```

Files `other_tasks/test123.py` and `balance_log/balance_log.py` contain task definitions like these:

```
# file other_tasks/test123.py
from celery import shared_task, Task

@shared_task()
def mytask():
    print("Test 1234!")

class TestTask01(Task):

    def run(self, client_id=None):
        logger.debug("TestTask01: run")
        return client_id
```

I run celery worker:

```
python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A settings.celery_settings worker
```

And this way it **can discover** tasks. I can call these tasks.

But then I try to use IPython:

```
In [1]: from settings.celery_settings import app

In [2]: app.tasks
Out[2]: 
{'celery.backend_cleanup': <@task: celery.backend_cleanup of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.chain': <@task: celery.chain of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.chord': <@task: celery.chord of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.chord_unlock': <@task: celery.chord_unlock of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.chunks': <@task: celery.chunks of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.group': <@task: celery.group of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.map': <@task: celery.map of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>,
 'celery.starmap': <@task: celery.starmap of XExchange:0x7f9f50267ac8>}
```

And apparently it **does not** discover the tasks.

It seems that when I call tasks explicitly, I first import them and specify exact path for the celery while call. That's why it works.

Question: how do I make them discovered to have a list of known tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I figured out that there is an additional parameter for `autodiscover_tasks` function:

```
def autodiscover_tasks(self, packages, related_name='tasks', force=False):
    ...
```

So, after setting `force=True` it turned to work!

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(pfiles, force=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample configuration:

conf/celeryconfig

```
from conf import settings

CELERYD_CHDIR='/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 360000
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
BROKER_URL='amqp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@rabbitmq:5672'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True
CELERY_TIMEZONE= "US/Eastern"
CELERY_IMPORTS=("hypervisor.esxi.vm_operations",
                "tools.deploy_tools",)
```

hypervisor/esxi/vm_operations.py

```
@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=300, max_retries=5)
def cancel_job(self, host_id=None, vm_id=None, job=None, get_job=False, **kwargs):
    pass
```

call_task.py

```
def call_task():
    log.info('api() | Sending task: ' + job_instance.reference)     
    celery = Celery()
    celery.config_from_object('conf.celeryconfig')
    celery.send_task("hypervisor.esxi.vm_operations.cancel_job",
                     kwargs={'job': job_instance,
                             'get_job': True},
                     task_id=job_instance.reference)
```

I use celery with Supervisor, and I start it from conf directory:

```
source ~/.profile
CELERY_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log
CELERYD_OPTS=" --loglevel=INFO --autoscale=10,5"
cd /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/conf
exec celery worker -n celeryd@%h -f $CELERY_LOGFILE $CELERYD_OPTS
```

Comment: So how can I get a list of known discovered tasks?

Comment: `from celery.task.control import  inspect`
`i = inspect().registered_tasks()`